# Node click event not firing for D3 Force Directed Graph

Tags: onclick, drag, d3.js

I'm trying to make nodes collapsed on click of node itself. The graph at present is force directed graph with draggable nodes.

Problem I'm facing is, after attaching the node click event I cannot get the click to fire instead node is displaced from it's position (like dragged on mouse click).

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var graph = { "links" : [ { "relation" : "Relation 0",
        "source" : 0,
        "target" : 1
      },
      { "relation" : "Relation 1",
        "source" : 1,
        "target" : 3
      },
      { "relation" : "Relation 3",
        "source" : 1,
        "target" : 4
      },
      { "relation" : "Relation 4",
        "source" : 1,
        "target" : 5
      },
      { "relation" : "Relation 5",
        "source" : 0,
        "target" : 2
      },
      { "relation" : "Relation 6",
        "source" : 2,
        "target" : 6
      }
    ],
  "nodes" : [ { "collapsed" : false,
        "collapsing" : 0,
        "id" : 0,
        "name" : "Node 0"
      },
      { "collapsed" : false,
        "collapsing" : 0,
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Node 1"
      },
      { "collapsed" : false,
        "collapsing" : 0,
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Node 2"
      },
      { "collapsed" : false,
        "collapsing" : 0,
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Node 3"
      },
      { "collapsed" : false,
        "collapsing" : 0,
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "Node 4"
      },
      { "collapsed" : false,
        "collapsing" : 0,
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "Node 5"
      },
      { "collapsed" : false,
        "collapsing" : 0,
        "id" : 6,
        "name" : "Node 6"
      }
    ]
};
var edges = [];
graph.links.forEach(function(e) {
  var sourceNode = graph.nodes.filter(function(n) {
    return n.id === e.source;
  })[0],
      targetNode = graph.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.target;
      })[0];

  edges.push({
    source: sourceNode,
    target: targetNode,
    relation: e.relation
  });
});

update();

function update() {
  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 8)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .on("click", togglenode)
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  console.log('drag started');
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  console.log('dragged');
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  console.log('drag ended');
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
function togglenode(d) {
  console.log('clicked node : '+d.id);
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    var inc = d.collapsed ? -1 : 1;
    recurse(d);

    function recurse(sourceNode){
      //check if link is from this node, and if so, collapse
      edges.forEach(function(l) {
        if (l.source.id === sourceNode.id){
          l.target.collapsing += inc;
          recurse(l.target);
        }
      });
    }

    d.collapsed = !d.collapsed;

    update();
  }
}
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 4.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.js"></script>

<svg width="800" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: If I click a node I get an alert. What doesn't work?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me in Google Chrome. Although, since your comment I double checked and verified that Click is working in  browsers (like Firefox, IE) except Chrome ... Is it working for you in Chrome?

Comment: Yep I used chrome

Comment: That's odd really, I don't see any console errors in chrome at my end, and I thought the click is just not happening, because it doesn't even log a console.log if I place it in the click handler function ...

Comment: And if I change "click" with "dblclick", I get the event fired as it should. It is only happening this way for Click event only.

Comment: The issue is coming back off and on again. It doesn't execute click handler randomly in Chrome browser. It's like if I've left the browser idle, I get back to the tab and the click handler is not working. It executes drag `start`, `dragged` and `end` events but not the click event. Only getting this behavior in Chrome.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/NDRukbTJ7 ... this is the console log i get when i clicked on Node.